# Annoying Xcode Error "file not found" #import <openssl/pkcs7.h>

Tags: ios, xcode, openssl

I did everything I knew.

I am trying to use OpenSSL on a project of mine but I have this error

**file not found**

```
 #import <openssl/pkcs7.h>
```

I am using this cocoapod right now:

```
pod 'OpenSSL-Classic', '1.0.1.i'
```

I had to setup my header and libraries search paths manually because this cocoapod did not do its homework. I copied this from a page on the web and I don't know if they are pointing to the right paths.

**library search paths**

```
$(inherited)
```

**header search paths**

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/OpenSSL-Classic/openssl"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/OpenSSL-Classic"
```

**other C Flags**

```
-isystem
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/OpenSSL-Classic"
-isystem
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/OpenSSL-Classic/openssl"
```

these four lines appear to be odd.

How do I know exactly where the headers are so I can solve the error and fill these fields properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize, I had forgotten to add the iOS headers to the git repo for version 1.0.1.i. I was using this cocoapod for a Mac project so I didn't notice.

You've probably sorted this out already but in case anyone else runs into the issue, just upgrade to version 1.0.1.j and the iOS headers will be there. Example Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

pod 'OpenSSL-Classic', '1.0.1.j'
```

As for why the header and library search paths were not added to your project automatically, I'm not sure. Did you remember to open the .xcworkspace instead of the .xcodeproj? Could you be missing $(inherited)? Any chance you have multiple targets in your projects? If so, you'll need to add something like the following in your Podfile:

```
link_with 'Tunesify', 'Tunesify Lite', 'Tunesify Tests'
```

replacing them with the names of your project's targets.